# How can I use a comparator in a circuit?

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, comparator, operational-amplifier

I am learning about how to use Operational Amplifiers as comparators. I understand that comparators are used to compare an input signal to a reference voltage. However, I am having a hard time visualizing this.

Say that I wanted a comparator with a reference voltage of 0 V (therefore, the output will be either positive or negative depending on whether the input signal is positive or negative, respectively). How could I draw a circuit like this?

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Electronics Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html) actually has a very good diagram of this.

[image]

Henceforth, when you're talking about reference voltages, it can depend on the structure of the reference voltage itself and it can be determined by Kirchhoff's Laws, i.e. Kirchhoff's Current Law.

[image]

If you have any more questions, I invite you to check out that hyperlink I put at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I've actually already read this tutorial, but I think my main point of confusion is: is there no feedback top in a comparator? Because they never draw it out...

Comment: @Bee You're welcome :) and that's correct. There aren't any feedback networks in these diagrams I have above. If there was any feedback, you would have your typical \$\displaystyle H=\frac{A}{1+A\beta}\$ transfer function.... Here, it's only \$H=A\$ so it's all feedforward.